# Create NSView directly from code

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsview

I would like to run a small program that opens couple of views. I do not want to use any xib files definition except of Basic AppDelegate.

Can someone direct me to any example of how can I open new window in Cocoa without defining it in xib file, just from the code?

This is what I am doing right now - what should I add to it?

```
- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification {
NSRect frameRect    = NSMakeRect(100, 100 , 256, 256);
NSView* tmpView     = [[NSView alloc] initWithFrame:frameRect];
[tmpView setHidden:NO];
[tmpView setNeedsDisplay:YES];
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: NSView does not implement makeKeyAndVisible, NSWindow does however - see answer below

Answer (score 2):

You need to create a new NSWindow and set its contentView to your new NSView like so:

```
NSWindow *myWindow = [[NSWindow alloc] initWithContentRect:NSMakeRect(100,100,256,256) styleMask:NSTitledWindowMask backing:NSBackingStoreBuffered defer:NO];
[myWindow setContentView:tmpView];
[myWindow makeKeyAndOrderFront:self];
```